# Dependency injection(Autofac equivalent for resolvebyname or key)

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container, autofac, light-inject

It was very handy with Autofac on dependency injection.

Recently I changed project where lightinject and unitycontainer uses. Here I am able to register a list of services with a name, but I'm unable to resolve by a name.

I tried to get it as `IEnumerable`. I'm getting all, but not the name I registered. So I'm unable to distinguish them.

What am I missing here?

Comment: To make the question more clear, you might want to add a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Steven: In Autofac We could call "container.ResolveNamed<IDeviceState>("online");"

https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html

Even in lightinject i could register
registrations.RegisterInstance<IApiEnvironmentSettings>(resultsWebEnvironmentSettings, "ResultsWebEnvironmentSettingsBase");

But not seeing a resolve for the same(Even could register with name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/ioc/property-injection-using-unity-container see the section Named Mapping

```
 public class Service {
     [Dependency("AName")]
     public IDependency Dependency {get;set;}
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think this will be the way in lightinject even. Let me go through one more